# How to resolve the error 'mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1000x1 and 3x512)' in NeuroDiffEq?

Tags: python, matrix, pde

I'm new to neural networks and have a basic understanding of how they are used. I am trying to solve the Spherical Laplace Equation with boundary conditions: u(r=0)=u(r=1)=0 for all theta and phi, using Artificial Neural Networks(ANN), in particular, using the NeuroDiffEq package of Python. Following is the code for the same

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
from neurodiffeq import diff 
from neurodiffeq.networks import FCNN 
from neurodiffeq.conditions import DirichletBVPSpherical
from neurodiffeq.solvers import SolverSpherical
from neurodiffeq.monitors import MonitorSpherical
from neurodiffeq.generators import Generator3D
%matplotlib notebook

laplace = lambda u, r, theta, phi: [
diff(((r**2)*diff(u,r,order=1)), r, order=1)/r**2 + 
diff((np.sin(theta))*diff(u,theta,order=1), theta, order=1)/((r**2)*(np.sin(theta))) +
diff(u,phi,order=2)/(r*np.sin(theta))**2
]

conditions = [
    DirichletBVPSpherical(r_0=0.0,f=0.0,r_1=1.0,g=0.0)
]

nets = [
FCNN(n_input_units=3, n_output_units=1, hidden_units=[512]),
]

monitor=MonitorSpherical(r_min=0.0,r_max=1.0,check_every=10,shape=(10,10,10),r_scale='linear',theta_min=0,theta_max=np.pi,phi_min=0,phi_max=2*np.pi)
monitor_callback = monitor.to_callback()

solver = SolverSpherical(
    pde_system=laplace,
    conditions=conditions,
    r_min=0.0,
    r_max=1.0,
    nets=nets,
    train_generator=Generator3D(grid=(10, 10, 10), xyz_min=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), xyz_max=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), method='equally-spaced'),
    valid_generator=Generator3D(grid=(10, 10, 10), xyz_min=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), xyz_max=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), method='equally-spaced-noisy'),
)

solver.fit(max_epochs=200, callbacks=[monitor_callback])

solution_neural_net_laplace = solver.get_solution()
```

I'm getting the following error

```
mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1000x1 and 3x512)
```

I'd appreciate any help in resolving this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated my answer, check if it works and remember to accept if it does.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it didn't work. I put hidden_units=512 and n_input_units=512. But I can't understand why n_input_units should be 512, because the inputs I'm giving to the network are r, theta, phi (i.e. 3).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the shape of `mat1` is not correct to be multiplied with `mat2`. It could be that you are using a grid of 10x10x10 = 1000, so try and make this something else i.e. 8x8x8 = 512, or you can try to make your input units = 1000 and see if that resolves the issue.

It could also be that `n_input_units = 512` or `n_input_units = 1000`, with the `n_hidden_units = [something else]` (depending on the changes in the grid you have made)

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that but it yields the same error. I think the columns of mat1 and rows of mat2 must be equal.

Comment: Does it yield *exactly* the same error? Or does the shapes in the brackets change?

Comment: Changing the grid to 8.8.8=512 changes the error to 'mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (512x1 and 3x512).'

Comment: I think the issue is with n_input_units, it should be 512 not 3.